# Osmdroid, how to create a static overlayitem that remains at the center of the map

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, osmdroid

I've searched high and low to find out how i can put an overlayitem that is not fixed to a GeoPoint (i.e geographical coordinates), but rather stays at a fixed point in the view (e.g. the center of the MapView) regardless of moving/scrolling in the map.

MapView has an .addView() method. I tried creating a view with a drawable but the view will be fixed on the map, exactly like an overlayitem, which is not what i want.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a framelayout with your map and a View. Fill a background in your view, and center it horizontally and vertically to make the background centered over your map.

```
<FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/form_lin_map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

       <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/form_mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />

        <View
         android:id="@+id/form_View"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/cross" />
    </FrameLayout>'
```

Comment: Use a static map service instead not rendering a dynamic map and disabling on click of that

Answer (score 0):

Surely if you just want something fixed to the centre of the display, rather than on the mapView, you're going about it wrong.  overlayItems ARE tied to GeoPoints, that's their purpose.

just create whatever it is as a new, normal, android view object of whatever type, and add it to the main view, on top of your MapView, laid out wherever you need it?